# How to enforce WebStorm not to ignore TypeScript insights in JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm, jsdoc

I'm using WebStorm 2022.2 (Build #WS-222.3345.108). In an empty new project, I've added the [ethers.js](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/tree/master/) project as [a custom third-party library](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#ws_js_custom_third_party_library). I've added the following HTML file to the project:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /** @type {Contract} */
        let contract;
        /** @type {ContractTransaction} */
        let tx = contract.myMethod();
        tx.wait();
    </script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body></html>
```

In the embedded script, WebStorm does correctly provide the [code-completion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/auto-completing-code.html) facilities for the variables whose types are annotated by the JSDoc; also, all of their corresponding fields and methods are correctly presented by the code-completion, colored appropriately, and *<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-Clicking* the tokens guides to the declaration points (most of which being in `.ts` files); even the [`ContractTransaction`](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/master/packages/contracts/src.ts/index.ts#L105), that is a TypeScript interface, a TypeScript concept that JavaScript lacks, works like a charm.

WebStorm does a great job in the HTML file, but when the identical code is put in an external JavaScript file (as in the second `<script>` tag with the `src` attribute in the HTML above), WebStorm ignores the TypeScript declarations altogether!

[image: WebStorm ignores TypeScript type declarations in JavaScript files]

The aforementioned ignorance (ignoring the TypeScript declarations) in the `index.js` file, causes the following issues:

- WebStorm believes the annotated type of `Contract` (at line 1) is declared in the [`contracts\lib\index.js`](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/master/packages/contracts/lib/index.js) file; ignoring the [corresponding TypeScript declaration](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/master/packages/contracts/src.ts/index.ts#L1140) causes WebStorm to not to perceive that the class has an ["index signature"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), which allows its objects to calmly expose any unforeseen properties; thus, it argues at line 4:
  `Unresolved function or method myMethod()`
- WebStorm complains about the `ContractTransaction` type annotation at line 3, arguing:
   `Unresolved variable or type 'ContractTransaction'` (while it correctly spotted [the corresponding declaration](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/master/packages/contracts/src.ts/index.ts#L105) in the HTML file!)
- Weirdly enough, WebStorm correctly recognizes [the declaration of the `wait()` method](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/master/packages/contracts/src.ts/index.ts#L106) at line 5; while in the previous entry, WebStorm argued it couldn't have found the type of `ContractTransaction`!! (only correctly & uninterestingly for our case, complains that `Promise returned from wait is ignored`)

So, how to force the WebStorm to utilize the relative TypeScript insights (denoted by the JSDoc type annotations) in an external JavaScript file (to have it consider the TypeScript insights, just like what it did on the HTML file)?

Comment: it works fine for me if I copy `contracts/src.ts/index.ts` to a new project; did you try excluding the `contracts\lib\index.js` and other generated stuff from indexing?

Comment: @lena Thanks for the response; That was a smart idea; if I copy the corresponding TypeScript files into the project, it similarly does work for me; but, copying the files over, doesn't sound promising: mostly because they need to be added as the project files (while they're just some third-party library files, not project files, they rationally should keep being "third-party libraries"), and secondly, whenever the library updates the chore of the copying process should be done all over again.

Comment: @lena Also, how do I exclude the "generated stuff: including the deflecting `.js` files" from indexing as you suggest (since they've been added as [custom third-party libraries](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#ws_js_custom_third_party_library))? The form on "Settings | Directories" doesn't seem to have anything to do with the third party libraries, any ideas?

Comment: just don't include these files in a library, include the `.ts` files only

Comment: @lena How? could you please elaborate.

Comment: Please, anyone, any ideas?!

Comment: when choosing files to include in a library, only choose the desired `.ts` files... *attach files* option allows selecting multiple individual files with `Ctrl+click`

Comment: @lena WebStrom doesn't seem to care about the TypeScript files **in a library** to have any effects on `.js` files (even by specifying the `.ts` files individually, [as you've suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73121970/how-to-enforce-webstorm-not-to-ignore-typescript-insights-in-javascript-files?noredirect=1#comment129272216_73121970)), it only cares about the files **"copied"** over as project files! It's like missing a fundamental feature; for the WebStorm, it's a shame!

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting weird/incorrect type completions, that might be because WebStorm is downloading type definitions itself to a different directory, which is sometimes the wrong version of the package.

You can disable this by opening the IDE's registry (`ctrl+alt+/`), and disabling `typescript.external.type.definitions`. This should force WebStorm to only uses the type definitions from the package that you've actually installed.

Comment: Thanks for the response; I've tried your suggestion to no avails, unfortunately. The thing is, WebStorm does not provide the TypeScript insights in the `.js` files (while it does do it even in the HTML files, as per the original post!)